# I am closing drop-down using jQuery, but need to double click to re-open - issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am closing drop-down using jQuery, but need to double click to re-open - issue.

My modal code snippet:

```
<div *ngIf="backEnd.isHeadLogin" class="date-range-filter">
    <span id="date-filter-toggle-span" dropdown #dropdownAllData="bs-dropdown" (onToggle)="toggled($event)" [autoClose]="false">
            <button id="date-dropdown" dropdownToggle>
                Choose date range
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu date-filter-content" *dropdownMenu aria-labelledby="date-dropdown">
                <!-- INNER HTML WILL BE HERE -->
                <p>INNER HTML</p> 
            </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

I am trying to close above drop-down using jQuery:

```
ngOnInit() {

    window.onclick =(event) => {
        var $trigger = $(".date-range-filter");
        
        if($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length){
            $('#date-filter-toggle-span').removeClass('open');          
            $("#date-dropdown").attr("aria-expanded",false);
        }
    }
    ....
    ....
}
```

If I click outside the drop-down, its getting close, but when I am trying to re-open it. it needs double click to open

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: why are you using `if($('#date-filter-toggle-span').hasClass('open'))` condition?

Comment: it should only applicable when dropdown is open, thats why

Comment: then `toggleClass` will do remove functionality only, you could have used `removeClass` only. Because we use `toggleClass` when we need to add/remove a class.

Comment: code snippet edited.. please check now

Comment: are you using bootstrap too?

Comment: yes.. but here.. I could not change the dropdown structure due to some conditions

Comment: can share the reproducible code on code sandbox editor or here.